# HOW to calculate percent difference with lag in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to calculate the difference in percent for the number of visitors in the last 4 weeks (week on week) for a restaurant.

My code lets me group days into weeks and sum the number of visitors into each week, then I used **lag** and **over** to try and get the percent difference but it's giving me rubbish for that column.

Here's my code

> ```
> SELECT
>
>  to_char(visit_date, 'IW') AS weeks, SUM(reserve_visitors) AS total_visitors,
> ((SUM(reserve_visitors)/lag(SUM(reserve_visitors), 1) OVER (ORDER BY to_char(visit_date, 'IW'))) -1) * 100 AS percentage_change
> FROM res_visitors
> WHERE visit_date BETWEEN '02/01/2017' AND '28/05/2017'
> GROUP BY weeks
> ORDER BY weeks DESC
> LIMIT 4
> ```

This is what I get

[image]

Does anyone know where the error might be?

Ideally I'd like to have a percentage which shows how much the number of visitors grew/shrank from one week to the next one

Thanks in advance and sorry if it might seem trivial to most of you here, I've gone around trying to figure it out but I just can't seem to find it

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  It is not really clear exactly what you are asking about.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the data type was wrong, I was dividing integers so any value under 0.5 is 0 and over 0.5 is 1.

I multiplied SUM(reserve_visitors) by 1.0 to make it a float and problem solved